# IOS issues with AVFoundation music player, working 50% of the time

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have some issues with the AVFoundation music player.

1) It does not start instantly, i guess buffering is slow on the simulator?

2) It only starts with sound 50% of the time, the other 50% it does not start, very unreliable

Here is my class

Music_Player.h

```
@interface Music_Player : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *trackPlaying;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isPlaying;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISlider *slider;

-(void)initTrack: (NSString *) track;

-(void)startPlayer;
-(void)pausePlayer;
-(void)stopPlayer;

-(void)sliderUp;
-(void)sliderDown;

@end
```

Music_Player.m

```
#import "Music Player.h"

@implementation Music_Player


@synthesize audioPlayer;

@synthesize trackPlaying;
@synthesize timer;

@synthesize isPlaying;

@synthesize slider;

-(void)initTrack:(NSString *)track
{
    /* Init slider */

    self.isPlaying = FALSE;
    self.trackPlaying = track;

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:self.trackPlaying ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSError *error = nil;

    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error];
    [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    /* Set slider max value */
    self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.slider.maximumValue = self.audioPlayer.duration - 5;
}

-(void)startPlayer
{
    if (self.isPlaying == TRUE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Pause clicked");
        [self.audioPlayer pause];
        self.isPlaying = FALSE;

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Play clicked");
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        self.isPlaying = TRUE;

        if (![self.timer isValid]) {
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (void)updateTime {

    if (self.isPlaying == TRUE) {

        NSTimeInterval currentTime = self.audioPlayer.currentTime;

        NSLog(@"%f", currentTime);
        // update UI with currentTime;
        slider.value = round(currentTime);
    }
}

-(void)pausePlayer
{
    if (self.isPlaying == TRUE)
    {
        [self.audioPlayer pause];
        self.isPlaying = FALSE;
    }
}

-(void)stopPlayer
{
    if (self.isPlaying == TRUE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Stop clicked");
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
        self.audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
        self.slider.value = round(self.audioPlayer.currentTime);
        self.isPlaying = FALSE;
    }
}

-(void)sliderUp
{
    if (self.isPlaying == FALSE)
    {
        self.audioPlayer.currentTime = round(slider.value);
        [self.audioPlayer play];
        self.isPlaying = TRUE;
    }
}

-(void)sliderDown
{
    if (self.isPlaying == TRUE)
    {
        self.isPlaying = FALSE;
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
    }
}

/* AUDIO PLAYER DELEGATES */

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"Did finish with, %c", flag);
}

- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}

@end
```

I just set up the slider property and init it with a track from my viewController

```
/* Init Music */
self.music_player = [[Music_Player alloc] init];
self.music_player.slider = self.slider;

[self.music_player initTrack:@"track1"];
```

And then i just pass on the Btn clicks and slider value changes to the music_player class, what could be the issue? I will be testing it on a iPhone tomorow, so could it just be a simulator issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. In `initWithData:error:`, is there an error set after being called?
2. Why not use `[AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL:error:]`? Eg:

   ```
   - (void)initTrack:(NSString *)track
   {
       self.isPlaying = NO;
       self.trackPlaying = track;

       NSBundle *mainBundle = ;
       NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:self.trackPlaying ofType:@"mp3"];
       NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

       NSError *error = nil;

       self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
   }
   ```

Comment: It is now, i just set the delegate, but it wasnt before

Comment: That method cannot find the file at all

Comment: Excuse me, we should use fileURLWithPath: here, not URLWithString:.